# how to upload files in cpanel file manager via xmlapi

Tags: file, upload, cpanel

I developing an application  which has static content builder for HTML pages. I am able to create ftp account and addondomain in cpanel via xmlapi but I dont know how to upload it in cpanel file manager. I want to know api1 or api2 syntax for file uploading in cpanel. Please help me. I am waiting for your response. I am using PHP for backend programing.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an **Upload** button on the main toolbar (see here - http://blogerr.net/getting-started-with-file-manager-in-cpanel/ ). If you can't see it, you may need to reset your cPanel configuration...